# Share a link to Bing maps, so that the map directly opens in Bird's Eye View

Tags: bing-maps

When I share a link to Bing maps, the map always opens in "standard mode". I want it to default or go directly to the Bird's Eye View mode.

What I want to do is this:

1. Open Bing maps
2. Switch to Bird's Eye View, zoom in, and rotate the view
3. Share a link to **that**, with the exact settings that I made.

So when someone opens my link, it should directly open in Bird's Eye View, zoom in exactly like I did, and so on.

Is it possible to share a link like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add style=o to the end of the url.  You must also specify a scene parameter also.  I find it easier to get what I want on the screen, then click the envelope in the lower left hand corner that is used to share the URL.

Check this page for more URL variables.
http://help.live.com/help.aspx?project=wl_local&market=en-us&querytype=topic&query=wl_local_proc_buildurl.htm

Comment: Regarding your edit for the envelope share link:  Interesting.  This results in a different url than using the Send link in the top left pane (which does not properly keep the zoom/view/rotation.

Comment: I don't understand myself why MS would use a different function to create the link when emailing and sharing are essentially the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, the envelope worked for me! I didn't notice it before, I always tried the Send link in the top left pane.

Comment: the URL for more variables doesent work anymore